# Swap Bottom and Header of page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJYCJ.png) [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KldOW.png)
I have a page where I display one word in one language on the top and the translation on the bottom. I need a functionality to swap these two so translation would go to to the top and so on, but then the user should be able to go back through the same button and have it in initial order.

I have tried to remove my grids and add them again but not only it always gives me different result of positioning but it also causes an exception if i repeat the process few times.

For now I have solved it with having 4 words and two of them have their visibility to false and once the user need to change their position I change it to true.

Like this

```
if (czechAndEnglishSwitched)
            {
                if (isHidden)
                {
                    HideLabels(null, null);
                }
                nameEng.IsVisible = false;
                nameEngSwitched.IsVisible = true;
                explanation.IsVisible = false;
                explanationSwitched.IsVisible = true;
                btnChangePositions.Text = "EN/CZ";
                defaultEnglishGrid.Children.Remove(btnMakeLargerName);
                parentOfDefaultCzechGrid.Children.Remove(btnMakeLarger);
                defaultEnglishGrid.Children.Add(btnMakeLarger);
                parentOfDefaultCzechGrid.Children.Add(btnMakeLargerName);
                czechAndEnglishSwitched = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (isHidden)
                {
                    HideLabels(null, null);
                }
                nameEng.IsVisible = true;
                nameEngSwitched.IsVisible = false;
                explanation.IsVisible = true;
                explanationSwitched.IsVisible = false;
                czechAndEnglishSwitched = true;
                defaultEnglishGrid.Children.Add(btnMakeLargerName);
                parentOfDefaultCzechGrid.Children.Add(btnMakeLarger);
                btnChangePositions.Text = "CZ/EN";
            }

What i have tried before
 private void ExchangeEnglishAndCzechVersion(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //if (czechAndEnglishSwitched)
            //{
            //    if (isHidden)
            //    {
            //        HideLabels(null, null);
            //    }
            //    mainGrid.Children.Remove(parentOfDefaultCzechGrid);
            //    mainGrid.Children.Remove(defaultEnglishGrid);

            //    mainGrid.Children.Add(defaultEnglishGrid);
            //    mainGrid.Children.Add(parentOfDefaultCzechGrid);

            //    mainGrid.Children.Add(gridButtons);
            //    mainGrid.Children.Add(gridDailyAmount);
            //    parentOfDefaultCzechGrid.Padding = new Thickness();

            //    defaultEnglishGrid.Children.Remove(btnBin);
            //    defaultEnglishGrid.Children.Remove(btnVisual);
            //    defaultEnglishGrid.Children.Add(buttonPlay);

            //    defaultCzechGrid.Children.Add(btnBin); 
            //    defaultCzechGrid.Children.Add(btnVisual);
            //    czechAndEnglishSwitched = false;
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    if (isHidden)
            //    {
            //        HideLabels(null, null);
            //    }
            //    mainGrid.Children.Remove(parentOfDefaultCzechGrid);
            //    mainGrid.Children.Remove(defaultEnglishGrid);

            //    mainGrid.Children.Add(defaultEnglishGrid);
            //    mainGrid.Children.Add(parentOfDefaultCzechGrid);


            //    defaultCzechGrid.Children.Remove(btnBin);
            //    defaultCzechGrid.Children.Remove(btnVisual);
            //    defaultCzechGrid.Children.Add(buttonPlay);
            //    defaultEnglishGrid.Children.Remove(buttonPlay);
            //    defaultEnglishGrid.Children.Add(btnVisual);
            //    defaultEnglishGrid.Children.Add(btnBin);

            //    parentOfDefaultCzechGrid.Padding = new Thickness();
            //    czechAndEnglishSwitched = true;
            //}
```

Now I am a beginner but I do think that setting their visibility to false and getting the data twice will just slow down the performance. I was also thinking of just having a new page.

xaml

```
<Grid HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="0" x:Name="mainGrid">
        <Grid BackgroundColor="{ DynamicResource MainWrapperBackgroundColor }"
                   RowSpacing="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition
                        Height="27*" />
                <RowDefinition
                        Height="27*" />
                <RowDefinition
                        Height="12*" />
                <RowDefinition
                        Height="Auto" />

                <!--<RowDefinition
                        Height="7*" />-->
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Padding="5"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid ><!--Margin="5"-->
                    <!-- CARD ONE -->
                    <grial:CardView  x:Name="defaultEnglishGrid"
                        Style="{ StaticResource ResponsiveLandscapeMarginStyle }"
                                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                CornerRadius="10" 
                            Padding="5">
                        <!-- Text -->
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition
                                                Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition
                                                Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="150" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="150" Grid.Row="0">
                                    <ScrollView>
                                    <controls:ExtendedWebView x:Name="nameEng" Opacity="1"  IsVisible="True" HeightRequest="150"/>
                                    </ScrollView>
                                    <ScrollView>
                                        <controls:ExtendedWebView x:Name="explanationSwitched"  VerticalOptions="Start" IsVisible="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" Opacity="1" HeightRequest="150"/>
                                    </ScrollView>

                            </Grid>
                                <!-- Column button Play-->
                                <Grid Padding ="5,0,0,0"
                                            Grid.Row="0"
                                            Grid.Column="1">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"></RowDefinition>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"></RowDefinition>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Label   x:Name="buttonPlay" Grid.Row="0"
                                             VerticalTextAlignment="Start"
                                             HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                                             Text="{ x:Static local:GrialIconsFont.Volume2 }"
                                             FontFamily="{ StaticResource IconsFontFamily }"
                                             TextColor="{ DynamicResource AccentColor }">
                                        <Label.GestureRecognizers >
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer
                                               Tapped="StartOrStopPlaying">
                                            </TapGestureRecognizer>
                                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <Label.FontSize>
                                            <OnIdiom
                                    x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                                    Phone="25"
                                    Tablet="30" />
                                        </Label.FontSize>
                                    </Label>
                                <Label   x:Name="buttonPause" 
                                             VerticalTextAlignment="Start"
                                             HorizontalTextAlignment="End"  IsVisible="False"
                                             Text="{ x:Static local:GrialIconsFont.AudioPause }"
                                             FontFamily="{ StaticResource IconsFontFamily }"
                                             TextColor="{ DynamicResource AccentColor }">
                                        <Label.GestureRecognizers >
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer
                                                Tapped="StartOrStopPlaying">
                                            </TapGestureRecognizer>
                                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <Label.FontSize>
                                            <OnIdiom
                                                x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                                                Phone="25"
                                                Tablet="30" />
                                        </Label.FontSize>
                                    </Label>
                                </Grid>
                                <!-- Column Button Plus -->
                            <Grid Padding ="5,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1"

                                            Grid.Column="1"
                                            VerticalOptions="End">
                                    <Label x:Name="btnMakeLargerName" 
                                           VerticalTextAlignment="End"
                                           HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                                           Text="{ x:Static local:GrialIconsFont.ZoomIn }"
                                           FontFamily="{ StaticResource IconsFontFamily }"
                                           TextColor="{ DynamicResource AccentColor }">
                                        <Label.GestureRecognizers >
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer
                                                Tapped="MakeWebViewLargeName">
                                            </TapGestureRecognizer>
                                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <Label.FontSize>
                                            <OnIdiom
                                    x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                                    Phone="25"
                                    Tablet="30" />
                                        </Label.FontSize>
                                    </Label>

                                </Grid>

                            </Grid>
                    </grial:CardView>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Padding="5"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid x:Name="defaultCzechGrid" >
                    <!--Margin="5"--> 
                    <!-- CARD TWO -->
                    <grial:CardView x:Name="parentOfDefaultCzechGrid" 
                                    Style="{ StaticResource ResponsiveLandscapeMarginStyle }"
                                    CornerRadius="10"   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                    Padding="0" >

                            <!-- Text -->
                            <Grid RowSpacing ="5">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" HeightRequest="150">
                                <ScrollView>
                                <controls:ExtendedWebView x:Name="explanation"  IsVisible="True"  VerticalOptions="Start"  HorizontalOptions="Start" Opacity="1" HeightRequest="150"/>
                                    </ScrollView>
                                <ScrollView>
                                    <controls:ExtendedWebView x:Name="nameEngSwitched" Opacity="1"  IsVisible="False"  HeightRequest="150"/>
                                </ScrollView> 
                           </Grid>


                                <!-- Column button Eye-->
                                <StackLayout Padding="2"
                                            Grid.Row="0" 
                                            Grid.Column="1"

                                    VerticalOptions="Start">
                                    <Label x:Name="btnVisual" 
                                           VerticalTextAlignment="Start"
                                           HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                                           Text="{ x:Static local:GrialIconsFont.Eye }"
                                           FontFamily="{ StaticResource IconsFontFamily }"
                                           TextColor="{ DynamicResource AccentColor }">
                                        <Label.GestureRecognizers >
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer
                                                Tapped="HideLabels">
                                            </TapGestureRecognizer>
                                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <Label.FontSize>
                                            <OnIdiom
                                    x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                                    Phone="25"
                                    Tablet="30" />
                                        </Label.FontSize>
                                    </Label>
                                </StackLayout>

                                <!-- Column Button Trash -->
                            <StackLayout Padding="2"
                                         Grid.Row="1"
                                         Grid.Column="1"
                                         Spacing="0" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                    <Label x:Name="btnBin"  
                                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                           HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                                           Text="{ x:Static local:IoniconsFont.IosTrash }"
                                           FontFamily="{ StaticResource Ionicons }"
                                           TextColor="{ DynamicResource AccentColor }">
                                        <Label.GestureRecognizers >
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer
                                                Tapped="RemoveWordFromUserDictionary">
                                            </TapGestureRecognizer>
                                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>

                                    <Label.FontSize>
                                            <OnIdiom
                                    x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                                    Phone="25"
                                    Tablet="30" />
                                        </Label.FontSize>
                                    </Label>

                                </StackLayout>

                                <!-- Column Button Plus -->
                            <StackLayout Padding="2"
                                         Grid.Row="3"
                                         Grid.Column="1"
                                         Spacing="0" VerticalOptions="End">
                                    <Label  x:Name="btnMakeLarger" 
                                            VerticalTextAlignment="End"
                                            HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                                            Text="{ x:Static local:GrialIconsFont.ZoomIn }"
                                            FontFamily="{ StaticResource IconsFontFamily }"
                                            TextColor="{ DynamicResource AccentColor }">
                                        <Label.GestureRecognizers >
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer
                                                Tapped="MakeWebViewLargeExplanation">
                                            </TapGestureRecognizer>
                                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <Label.FontSize>
                                            <OnIdiom
                                    x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                                    Phone="25"
                                    Tablet="30" />
                                        </Label.FontSize>
                                    </Label>

                                </StackLayout>

                            </Grid>

                    </grial:CardView>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <!-- CARD Three -->
            <Grid Grid.Row="2" Padding="5,2,5,0"  RowSpacing="10" x:Name="gridButtons" >
                <Grid>
                    <grial:CardView
                                Style="{ StaticResource ResponsiveLandscapeMarginStyle }"

                                HeightRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                CornerRadius="10" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        Padding="0,0,0,3">
                        <Grid Padding="0"
                                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition
                                Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition
                                Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
                            <!-- BUTTONS GRID -->
                            <Grid Margin="0"
                                  ColumnSpacing="10"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                            VerticalOptions="Center">

                                <!-- Rating Button Grid -->
                                <Grid Grid.Row="0"    ColumnSpacing="15" Padding="0,2,0,0">
                                    <!-- One -->
                                    <Button x:Name="firstRateBtn"  Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="1"  Style="{ StaticResource CircleActionButtonFlatStyle }" VerticalOptions="Start"  HeightRequest="50" CornerRadius="25" WidthRequest="50" Clicked="RateOneAndShowOtherword"/>
                                <!-- Two -->
                                    <Button x:Name="secondRateBtn"  Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="2" Style="{ StaticResource CircleActionButtonFlatStyle }" VerticalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="50" CornerRadius="25" WidthRequest="50" Clicked="RateTwoAndShowOtherword" />
                                <!-- Three-->
                                    <Button  x:Name="thirdRateBtn"   Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="3" Style="{ StaticResource CircleActionButtonFlatStyle }" VerticalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="50" CornerRadius="25" WidthRequest="50" Clicked="RateThreeAndShowOtherword"  />
                                <!-- Four -->
                                    <Button x:Name="fourthRateBtn"  Grid.Column="3" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="4"  Style="{ StaticResource CircleActionButtonFlatStyle }" VerticalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="50" CornerRadius="25" WidthRequest="50" Clicked="RateFourAndShowOtherword"/>
                                <!-- Five -->
                                    <Button  x:Name="fifthRateBtn"  Grid.Column="4" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="5"  Style="{ StaticResource CircleActionButtonFlatStyle }" VerticalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="50" CornerRadius="25" WidthRequest="50" Clicked="RateFiveAndShowOtherword" />
                                </Grid>

                            </Grid>
                            <!-- Labels -->
                            <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Padding="0,2,0,0">
                                <!--Text Wrong-->
                                <Label Text="{ grial:Translate A_LabelCorrectWrong }" FontSize="14" Style="{ StaticResource LabelBoldStyle }" TextColor="{ DynamicResource CircleActionButtonFlatTextColor }" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Start"
                            IsVisible="{grial:OnOrientationBool
                                    Default='true',
                                    LandscapePhone='false'}" />

                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </grial:CardView>
                </Grid>

            </Grid>
            <!-- CARD Four -->
            <Grid Grid.Row="3" Padding="5,5,5,5" x:Name="gridDailyAmount">
                <Grid >
                    <grial:CardView
                                Style="{ StaticResource ResponsiveLandscapeMarginStyle }"

                                VerticalOptions="Fill"
                                CornerRadius="10"
                        Padding="0">
                        <Grid Margin="0"
                        ColumnSpacing="0"

                        Padding="{ grial:OnOrientationThickness Default='20', LandscapePhone='20,8'
                        }">

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition
                                Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition
                                Height="*" />

                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <!--Text Daily dose-->
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Margin="0"  Grid.Column ="0" Text="Dnešní dávka" FontSize="15" TextColor="{ DynamicResource CircleActionButtonFlatTextColor }" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start"
                            IsVisible="{grial:OnOrientationBool
                                    Default='true',
                                    LandscapePhone='false'}" />
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Margin="0"  Grid.Column ="1" x:Name="amountOfWordForToday" FontSize="15" TextColor="{ DynamicResource CircleActionButtonFlatTextColor }" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="End"
                            IsVisible="{grial:OnOrientationBool
                                    Default='true',
                                    LandscapePhone='false'}" />
                            <!--Text Amount of words-->
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0" Text="Slovíček ve slovníku" FontSize="15" TextColor="{ DynamicResource CircleActionButtonFlatTextColor }" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                            IsVisible="{grial:OnOrientationBool
                                    Default='true',
                                    LandscapePhone='false'}" />
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Margin="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="amountOfWordsInDictionary"  FontSize="15" TextColor="{ DynamicResource CircleActionButtonFlatTextColor }" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="End"
                            IsVisible="{grial:OnOrientationBool
                                    Default='true',
                                    LandscapePhone='false'}" />                      
                        </Grid>
                    </grial:CardView>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>       
    </Grid>
```

Do you have any suggestion how to solve this?

Comment: Your solution is really specific. Would you mind to add an image to visualize what you want to achieve?

Comment: i will add it in few minutes

Comment: How does your solution look with four words?

Comment: i have their visibility set to false, so once i press the button the other pair is visible. It works, but i just think it can be done some other way

Comment: nameEng.IsVisible = false;
                nameEngSwitched.IsVisible = true;
                explanation.IsVisible = false;
                explanationSwitched.IsVisible = true;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to change the position of the layout , and don't need four words to control the Visible either .

You could change the binding in code to achieve the `swap`effect .

Here is a simple example .

#### Xaml

```
  <StackLayout>
        <Button Text="Swap" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>

        <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="button1" Text="{Binding EN}"/>
            <Button x:Name="button2" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding CZ}"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
```

#### ViewModel

```
public class Modelss : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string en;
    public string EN
    {
        get { return en; }
        set
        {
            en = value;

            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(en));
        }
    }


    private string cz;
    public string CZ
    {
        get { return cz; }
        set
        {
            cz = value;

            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(cz));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

#### Page

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class Page10 : ContentPage
{

    Modelss model;

    public Page10()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        model = new Modelss();
        model.EN = "bricho";
        model.CZ = "a belly";


        this.BindingContext = model;
    }


    bool isSwap=false;
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        isSwap = !isSwap;

        button1.RemoveBinding(Button.TextProperty);
        button2.RemoveBinding(Button.TextProperty);


        if (isSwap)
        {
            button1.SetBinding(Button.TextProperty, "CZ");
            button2.SetBinding(Button.TextProperty, "EN");
        }
        else
        {
            button1.SetBinding(Button.TextProperty, "EN");
            button2.SetBinding(Button.TextProperty, "CZ");
        }                         
    }
}
```

[image]